# Tabela com coluna e scrolls fixos

Tags: html, css

Estou precisando fazer uma tabela com a primeira coluna fixa e com scroll lateral fixo, conforme o exemplo deste link: 
http://hazaa.com.au/blog/how-to-create-an-html-table-with-frozen-headers-and-columns/

Código fonte:https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5e237543fffb2891&id=5E237543FFFB2891%21192

O problema, é que neste exemplo foram utilizadas dimensões fixas para tudo ("px"), e eu preciso que o tamanho seja adequado de acordo com a tela ("%"). Tentei substituir tudo por %, mas não consigo de jeito nenhum habilitar o scroll horizontal..

Alguém consegue dar uma força?

Answer (score 1):

Se você utiliza o Bootstrap 3, o pessoal do Stack Overflow [respondeu sua pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737306/bootstrap-3-responsive-table-with-fixed-first-column). Caso não, há outras opções.

1. [Sticky Tables](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/) (é meio responsivo);
2. [Tem essa biblioteca também](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/);
3. [Responsive Tables](http://trydevkit.com/blog-post/responsive-tables-best-practices-and-examples/ee7961a6-a22e-610b-70d0-533c85cc59b6).

Espero ter te ajudado. Creio que para dispositivos móveis não se use % e sim `rem` ou `em`. Mas não posso te confirmar 100%.

Comment: %, `em` são em equivalentes em geral. `rem` se comporta de maneira um pouco diferente, mas nada tem relacionado com o uso em dispositivos móveis em si. http://designshack.net/articles/typography/whats-the-deal-with-em-and-rem/

Comment: Obrigado @FuadSaud, creio que não sabia corretamente a diferença entre `em` e `rem`.